# How many animals have been found burned to death in the Kenow fire area?

Tags: canada, national-parks, forest-fires

The [Kenow fire](http://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/ab/waterton/securite-safety/feu-fire-kenow/feu-fire-images-04) burned ~38,100 hectares of forest in BC and in Waterton Lakes National Park. There are rumours surfacing about the number of animals found dead in the park thus far. Ground crews have apparently found at least nine burnt grizzly bears, and they're finding cougars dead up in trees. Cougars tree in the face of danger, so it's possible that every cougar in the park could have died in the flames.

Are there any official stats as to how many animals have been identified thus far?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I associate destroy with inanimate objects and killed or died with living things. So in my opinion "How many animals died in ..." would be more appropriate - I will leave this to a native English speaker though.

Comment: @imsodin "Destroy" is a term used in association with euthanizing an animal you don't intend to keep for food or any other reason. Whereas "taken" for contrast is a tern used to describe an animal killed for food or some other use. I used the word destroy to emphasize the unfortunate loss of the animals.

Comment: +1 for this question, even though it makes feel like throwing up.  I think of the animals every time there is a fire.  Our car struck a deer who burst on the road fleeing from the Foresta fire in Yosemite several years ago. Do you know of a group that whose mission is to help animal victims of natural disasters?  We'd like to contribute.

Comment: @ab2 No, I just finished reading on the Parks Canada website that the animals that return to the park after a fire really benefit from the blaze. It's almost like a reset button. The long term effects of forest fires are really heathy for both the plant and wildlife.